# Is my electric power cord creating magnetic field when coiled?

Tags: electromagnetism, everyday-life, magnetic-fields

Simple question. But I was wondering, does my mac power cord create a magnetic field when its all coiled?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.carexcanada.ca/en/magnetic_fields/. The DC part of the cord, after the transformer will have a unidirectional magnetic field. The ac one a varying  sinusoidally field which will eventually produce electromagnetic radiation at 50 or 60 Herz

Comment: Hi Anna, for me this is a fantastic response, the detail is much appreciated, many thanks.  I am however unsure how to mark this as the accepted answer as its a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It doesn't have to be coiled. Magnetic fields will be created as long as you have a current through a wire.
2. Coiling may make the field strength stronger.
3. How strong the field strength is in practice also depends on the current through the wire and [whether your power cable has shielding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shielded_cable).

Answer (score 0):

I invite you to try to measure that field. Both the AC and DC portions of cable have currents flowing in the opposite direction at very close proximity to each other.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/391971)